# AWS iOS Swift Credential Issue

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have been recently given the following details..

1. User Name
2. Access Key Id
3. Secret Access Key
4. Bucket Name
5. Folder Name

I have assigned the bucket name but i still keep getting the error aas to check AUTHENTICATION.

What do I do?

Error:

> Couldn't read credentials provider configurations from Info.plist. Please check your Info.plist if you are providing the SDK configuration values through Info.plist.

Comment: Couldn't read credentials provider configurations from `Info.plist`. Please check your `Info.plist` if you are providing the SDK configuration values through `Info.plist`.

Comment: Hi, could you give some more details? How are you initializing the service configuration? Are you using AWSS3TransferUtility or AWSS3 client? Are you using the default service client?

Comment: How you did an initial configuration of AWS in your project?